# Dynamic partial references in Mustache

Tags: php, mustache

Wondering if it is possible to dynamically reference a partial based on a variable.

Consider this overly simplified context, template and example rendering below -

**test.php**

```
<?php

$context = [
    //...
    "partial" => "partial/to/include"
    //...
];

echo (new Mustache_Engine)->render(
    "<h1>Test template</h1> {{> {{ partial }} }}",
    $context
);
```

Now it's pretty obvious that this won't work, but it illustrates a point (I hope). Is there a clean solution to solve this?

I can only see three solutions to myself, none are ideal -
1. Helpers
2. Extending the Mustache_Engine class
3. If/Not blocks and set the template name as a key with a boolean value inside the context (There's a lot of partials that can potentially be referenced and this is unmaintainable)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit contrived, but it seems you can achieve it by defining a function that renders the include like this:

```php
$context = [
    'partial' => function () { return '{{> partial/to/include }}'; },
];

echo (new Mustache_Engine)->render(
    '<h1>Test template</h1> {{{ partial }}}',
    $context
);
```

If you're going to use this more than twice, you can clean it up and have something like this:

```php
function dynamic_partial($partial) {
    return function () use ($partial) {
        return "{{> $partial }}";
    };
}

$context = [
    'partial' => dynamic_partial('partial/to/include'),
];

echo (new Mustache_Engine)->render(
    '<h1>Test template</h1> {{{ partial }}}',
    $context
);
```

There may be a cleaner way of doing it, but this is the one I found.